# Error Mapbox Navigation Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, mapbox

Estoy tratando de implementar Mapbox Navigation en Xamarin Android pero al compilar lanza el siguiente error, XA4212: Type `Com.Mapbox.Services.Android.Location.LostLocationEngine` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported., alguien puede ayudarme con esto. Gracias.

El código utilizado es este

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    const string MAPBOX_KEY = "pk.eyJ1IjoibmF4YW10ZXN0IiwiYSI6ImNqNWtpaG1oYTJqZmQyd28yM2tsdDhucmEifQ.Zr35ENq9tziBBDAbdeU2dw";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Mapbox.GetInstance(this, MAPBOX_KEY);

        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        btn.Click += delegate {
            BuildRoute();
        };
    }

    async void BuildRoute()
    {
        MapboxNavigation navigation = new MapboxNavigation(this, MAPBOX_KEY);

        Point origin = Point.FromLngLat(-77.03613, 38.90992);
        Point destination = Point.FromLngLat(-77.0365, 38.8977);

        var response = await NavigationRoute
            .GetBuilder()
            .AccessToken(Mapbox.AccessToken)
            .Origin(origin)
            .Destination(destination)
            .Build()
            .GetRouteAsync();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: Comparte el codigo de tu clase o lo que estés intentando.